# Longer Twitter Timeline

Tags: twitter

When I scroll down my Twitter timeline in the web site I can only see tweets up to the last day (I guess this depends in how many people I follow).

Is there a way to see a longer timeline?

Comment: How many do you follow? Following 160 here and it shows up more than two days fine on the web

Comment: I'm following 600+